# What could Donald Trump do to damage the economy of Turkey?

Tags: donald-trump, turkey

Recently US President Donald Trump has threatened to ["destroy the Turkish economy"](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/oct/16/trump-letter-erdogan-turkey-invasion) in retaliation for Turkish President Erdoğan's military decisions following the removal of US troops from Syria.

What actions, if any, can the Trump administration take to cause severe damage to the Turkish economy? Is there anything he could realistically do on his own to cause this, or is there an option that could be achieved with support from congress or allies?

Comment: *can* seems rather broad. Within what bounds are you looking for an answer? Limited to what the president can do unilaterally without support from congress or allies?

Comment: I've edited the question with clarification - I'd be satisfied with any reasonable justification for Trump's threat.

Comment: Congress wants to do more than Trump presently, so this question is a bit backwards. https://edition.cnn.com/2019/10/14/politics/donald-trump-congress-turkey-sanctions-syria/index.html A simple answer would be "agree with Congress".

Comment: @fizz do we know that or suspect that?  While Trump is a mix between a dove/isolationist militarily, he's pretty aggressive trade wise.  And I defy you to point to a consistent Trump doctrine.

Comment: @KDog https://www.al-monitor.com/pulse/originals/2019/10/congress-noncommittal-turkey-sanctions.html